# Change the learning rate in Neural Net node SPSS Modeler

Tags: spss-modeler

I am trying to fit a model on continuous variable using Neural net node available in SPSS Modeler 18.2.1. But it  cannot find any place where I can change or fine-tune the hyper-parameters like learning rate, or optimizer momentum etc...

Is there a way to do it by scripting using Python ? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the automated data preparation node before the neural networks node?
You can also define parameters using the execution mode (using python or the legacy script - clementine).

Check links below:

[Automated Data Preparation node](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/idh_idd_adp_objective.htm)

[Parameters using script](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/stream_parameterstab.htm)

Comment: Hi Erica, I am more interested in changing the learning rate and optimizer. It is neither in Automated Dataprep nor in Scripting documentation.

Comment: Did you read the manual related to python? ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/modeler/18.2/en/ModelerScriptingAutomation.pdf